# How does one discover [non-Apple] Audio Units with Audio Component Services?

Tags: macos, core-audio, audiounit

In OS X, I am trying to find an example of how to discover all the Audio Units installed on an end-users system and get back that information for display and use.

I know that Audio Component is involved with that task, but I am completely baffled how to go about doing it. All the examples I come across are based around finding a 'known' Apple AU with AudioComponentFindNext, and I cannot find an example for discovering anything else.

Can anyone point me to an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a `AudioComponentDescription` struct using `0` as a wildcard for type, subtype, and manufacturer.  Pass that to `AudioComponentFindNext`:

```
AudioComponentDescription acd = { 0 };
AudioComponent comp = nullptr;
while((comp = AudioComponentFindNext(comp, &acd)) {
  // Found an AU
}
```

Here is some relevant documentation from the header:

```
@function       AudioComponentFindNext
@abstract       Finds an audio component.
@discussion     This function is used to find an audio component that is the closest match
                to the provided values.
@param          inComponent
                    If NULL, then the search starts from the beginning until an audio
                    component is found that matches the description provided by inDesc.
                    If non-NULL, then the search starts (continues) from the previously
                    found audio component specified by inComponent, and will return the next
                    found audio component.
@param          inDesc
                    The type, subtype and manufacturer fields are used to specify the audio
                    component to search for. A value of 0 (zero) for any of these fields is
                    a wildcard, so the first match found is returned.
@result         An audio component that matches the search parameters, or NULL if none found.
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the provided AVAudioUnitComponentManager components function to get audio units.

It will return an array of audio units that match the `AudioComponentDescription` you pass.
Command click `AudioComponentDescription` and `kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice` to see the various values you can use.

```swift
// Exemple to get instruments audio units
var match = AudioComponentDescription()
match.componentType = kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice
        
let audioUnitComponents = AVAudioUnitComponentManager.shared().components(matching: match)
```

Comment: please provide some explanation to your answer

Comment: Done ;) It required some imagination, because it is almost a one-line code. It was much more difficult in 2014